# Matlab: How to combine two vectors in one

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vector, concatenation

I have two vectors

```
A = [...] %size 1x320
B = [...] %size 1x192
```

I would like to combine the two vectors in one but the way I want to combine them is the following:

Take the first 5 elements of vector A then add 3 elements from vector B add the next 5 elements from vector A then add the next element from vector B and so on until the both vectors are combined in one. I think the process should be repeated 64 times since `320/5=64` and `192/3=64`.

Is there any built-in Matlab function to do that?

Comment: See my edit for a second solution that does not involve for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a built-in function that does exactly that, but the following will do what you want:

```
A=randi(10,1,320);
B=randi(10,1,192);
C=zeros(1,length(A)+length(B));
for i=1:5
    C(i:8:end)=A(i:5:end);
end
for i=6:8
    C(i:8:end)=B(i-5:3:end);
end
```

Then the array `C` is the combined array.

Edit: Another way to do that, without for loops:

```
A=randi(10,1,320);
B=randi(10,1,192);
A_new=reshape(A,5,[]);
B_new=reshape(B,3,[]);
C=[A_new;B_new];
C=reshape(C,[1,numel(C)]);
```

In this solution, by specifying the third parameter in `reshape(A,5,[])` to be `[]`, we allow it to adjust the number of columns according to the length of A, given that the number of rows in the reshaped array is 5. In addition, `numel(C)` is the total number of elements in the array `C`. So this solution can be easily generalized to higher number of arrays as well.